# How to properly use lookup columns in content types in the content type hub

Tags: content-type

I created one content type called client in the content type hub.
THen I created another content type called project on the content type hub, this one should have a lookup column to the client.

As the list does not exist, I created it in the content type hub.

I also created the list for clients in the content type hub, I exported both lists as templates (STP)

Then I created the lists based on the templates on the destination site collection, client list works perfect.

However project list does not work, it says the list does not found (the lookup list), I had to manually delete the lookup column on the destination content type, and add it again.

This is not a nice solution, and I guess if the content type project is published again, then I will lose my changes over and over.

Any nice solution to this problem?

Comment: Converting lookup to managed term set is the best option.

Comment: +1 nice idea! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of lookup use a Managed Metadata Term field.

A Managed Metadata column is a can be added to content types to enable site users to select values from a specific term set of managed terms and apply these values to their content. You can create and configure a Managed Metadata column to map to an existing term set or term, or you can create a new term set specifically for a Managed Metadata column.

More information https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Create-a-Managed-Metadata-column-8fad9e35-a618-4400-b3c7-46f02785d27f

Comment: if I use managed metadata field, for client name for example, the term is saved into the group for the content type hub